# Как не декодировать JSON для VkApi?

Tags: json, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота для vk.com, который будет постить картинки на страницу группы. Есть вот такая функция:

```
upload_url = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=Settings.owner_id)
    files = {'photo': open('img/img.jpg', 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(upload_url["upload_url"], files=files)  # отправляем файл
    print(r.text)
    dict_param = json.loads(r.text)  # Парсим json
    server = dict_param["server"]
    hash_photo = dict_param["hash"]
    photo = dict_param["photo"]
    save = api.photos.saveWallPhoto(group_id="143550839", server=server, hash=hash_photo, photo=photo)
```

saveWallPhoto возвращает такую ошибку:
*vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 121. Invalid hash.* 
Погуглив, узнал, что такая ошибка может возникать из-за декодирования JSON'а, который возвращает сервер и хранится у меня в переменной r. 
Как обратиться к значениям JSON, не декодируя его?

Comment: Нельзя декодировать photo, а вы его и так не декодируете; в этом плане ваш код корректен. Ошибка возникает из-за чего-то другого

Comment: Что выводит print(r.text)?

Comment: @andreymal https://goo.gl/380ILj примерно как здесь.

Comment: 1- используйте `r.json()`, а не `json.loads(r.text)` 2- забудьте совет, который говорит, что из json документа следует доставать информацию, используя что-то другое кроме json парсера (или вы не так поняли или совет плохой).

Comment: В этом репозитрии есть пример загрузки фото https://github.com/Kwentar/vkontakte-api-for-python

Comment: @ Andrio Skur Это старое API, но все равно спасибо, что ответили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в

```
upload_url = api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=Settings.owner_id)
```

group_id должна быть больше нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Через регулярные выражения, используйте

```
result = re.search(r'(str[\: ]+)(value)', json)
```

где str - требуемый параметр, value - его значение, json - ваш JSON, а в переменной result будут возвращаться все совпадения.

Регулярка приблизительно, надо будет адаптировать для конкретного поиска.

Comment: Это разве код для `python` ?

Comment: @Alban да, сорри, привел пример для PHP, но для Python есть схожая функция re.search().